# Android Studio, saving pics and video not working

Tags: java, android, camera

I'm trying to learn how to make android apps.
I adapted a code to take pictures and videos. Not using the camera app, but my own. I got this code to image and video.

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
private void recordVideo() {
    if (videoCapture != null) {

        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, timestamp);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");

        try {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            videoCapture.startRecording(
                    new VideoCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(
                            getContentResolver(),
                            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            contentValues
                    ).build(),
                    getExecutor(),
                    new VideoCapture.OnVideoSavedCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onVideoSaved(@NonNull VideoCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Video has been saved successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(int videoCaptureError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error saving video: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

private void capturePhoto() {
    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, timestamp);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");



    imageCapture.takePicture(
            new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(
                    getContentResolver(),
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    contentValues
            ).build(),
            getExecutor(),
            new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Photo has been saved successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error saving photo: " + exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    );

}
```

Everything looks fine, but when I hit the Picture Button or Recording Button, I have a positive answer, that my picture/video have been taken, but there is nothing on my files.
When I checkk the Android Studio Run, I find this message:

```
03/15 16:37:47: Launching 'app' on OUKITEL WP7. App restart successful without requiring a re-install. $ adb shell am start -n "com.palfs.cameraxinjava/com.palfs.cameraxinjava.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER Connected to process 4436 on device 'oukitel-wp7-OUKITELWP7006944'. Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page. I/s.cameraxinjav: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni W/re-initialized>: type=1400 audit(0.0:19902): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:mtk_amslog_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=14068 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c109,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:mtk_amslog_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 E/libc: **Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sys.activitylog"** W/s.cameraxinjav: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking) W/s.cameraxinjav: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking) W/s.cameraxinjav: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking) W/s.cameraxinjav: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking) W/s.cameraxinjav: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking) W/s.cameraxinjav: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/WindowInsets;->CONSUMED:Landroid/view/WindowInsets; (light greylist, reflection) W/s.cameraxinjav: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->getAccessibilityDelegate()Landroid/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate; (light greylist, linking) W/s.cameraxinjav: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection) W/s.cameraxinjav: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection) I/CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline I/SurfaceFactory: [static] sSurfaceFactory = com.mediatek.view.impl.SurfaceFactoryImpl@48e6a2a D/CameraRepository: Added camera: 0 D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@c2e0f91, this = DecorView@380fef6[MainActivity] I/Camera2CameraInfo: Device Level: INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL D/CameraRepository: Added camera: 1 I/Camera2CameraInfo: Device Level: INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL D/CameraRepository: Added camera: 2 I/Camera2CameraInfo: Device Level: INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL D/CameraValidator: Verifying camera lens facing on WP7, lensFacingInteger: null W/s.cameraxinjav: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Insets;->of(IIII)Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking) D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7730e97000) I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0 I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4 D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2 I/GED: [GT]_get_procNameprocess pid(4436) I/GED: [GT]_getprocess name(com.palfs.cameraxinjava) D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x7730e97000,api=1) E/IMGSRV: :0: ObtainWindowParams: *piMaxBufCount is 0 I/libEGL: [MTK Game SDK] low_latency_mode(0) pid(-1) property(-1) D/DeferrableSurface: Surface created[total_surfaces=1, used_surfaces=0](androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest$2@34f50ea} D/CameraOrientationUtil: getRelativeImageRotation: destRotationDegrees=0, sourceRotationDegrees=90, isOppositeFacing=true, result=90 I/BufferQueue: [unnamed-4436-0](this:0x771e0d3800,id:0,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) BufferQueue core=(4436:com.palfs.cameraxinjava) E/libc: **Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.sf.stc_interval" E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.dump"** W/s.cameraxinjava: type=1400 audit(0.0:19903): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:graphics_debug_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=14043 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c109,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:graphics_debug_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 W/s.cameraxinjava: type=1400 audit(0.0:19904): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:debug_bq_dump_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=14004 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c109,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:debug_bq_dump_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 I/BufferQueueConsumer: [unnamed-4436-0](this:0x771e0d3800,id:0,api:0,p:-1,c:4436) connect(C): consumer=(4436:com.palfs.cameraxinjava) controlledByApp=true W/s.cameraxinjava: type=1400 audit(0.0:19905): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:debug_bq_dump_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=14004 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c109,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:debug_bq_dump_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 W/s.cameraxinjava: type=1400 audit(0.0:19906): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:graphics_debug_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=14043 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c109,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:graphics_debug_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.dump" I/BufferQueueConsumer: [unnamed-4436-0](this:0x771e0d3800,id:0,api:0,p:-1,c:4436) setConsumerName: unnamed-4436-0 E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.line" E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.dump" I/BufferQueueConsumer: [ImageReader-3264x2448f100m2-4436-0](this:0x771e0d3800,id:0,api:0,p:-1,c:4436) setConsumerName: ImageReader-3264x2448f100m2-4436-0 E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.line" I/BufferQueueConsumer: [ImageReader-3264x2448f100m2-4436-0](this:0x771e0d3800,id:0,api:0,p:-1,c:4436) setDefaultBufferSize: width=3264 height=2448 D/DeferrableSurface: Surface created[total_surfaces=2, used_surfaces=0](androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@fc63551} D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@dca1fc9[id=0]} Use case ImageCapture:androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-6ec784b0-678f-42ea-9e2c-bb74999cef0f ACTIVE D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and attached use case: [] for camera: 0 I/OMXClient: IOmx service obtained I/OMXClient: IOmx service obtained I/OMXClient: IOmx service obtained W/OMXUtils: do not know color format 0x7f000200 = 2130706944 W/OMXUtils: do not know color format 0x7f000789 = 2130708361 I/ACodec_vilte: set I frame rate I/ACodec_vilte: set framerate I/ACodec_vilte: setMTKParameters, width: 1920 I/ACodec_vilte: setMTKParameters, height: 1080 I/ACodec_roi: + setRoiParameters 263 I/ACodec_roi: - setRoiParameters 269 I/ACodec: setupAVCEncoderParameters with [profile: High] [level: Level41] I/ACodec: [OMX.MTK.VIDEO.ENCODER.AVC] cannot encode color aspects. Ignoring. I/ACodec: [OMX.MTK.VIDEO.ENCODER.AVC] cannot encode HDR static metadata. Ignoring. I/ACodec: setupVideoEncoder succeeded I/ACodec_vilte: set I frame rate I/ACodec_vilte: set framerate I/ACodec_vilte: setMTKParameters, width: 1920 I/ACodec_vilte: setMTKParameters, height: 1080 I/ACodec_roi: + setRoiParameters 263 I/ACodec_roi: - setRoiParameters 269 W/OMXUtils: do not know color format 0x7f000789 = 2130708361 W/H2BGraphicBufferProducer: getConsumerUsage is not fully supported D/DeferrableSurface: Surface created[total_surfaces=3, used_surfaces=0](androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@1d51342} I/OMXClient: IOmx service obtained I/ACodec_roi: + setRoiParameters 263 I/ACodec_roi: - setRoiParameters 269 D/AudioRecord: set(): 0x771e07f900, inputSource 1, sampleRate 48000, format 0x1, channelMask 0xc, frameCount 3840, notificationFrames 0, sessionId 0, transferType 0, flags 0, opPackageName com.palfs.cameraxinjava uid -1, pid -1 D/AudioRecord: openRecord_l: 0x771e07f900, mCblk = 0x771a47e000 I/VideoCapture: source: 1 audioSampleRate: 48000 channelConfig: 12 audioFormat: 2 bufferSize: 7680 D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@dca1fc9[id=0]} Use case androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture@295f763 ACTIVE D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and attached use case: [] for camera: 0 D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@dca1fc9[id=0]} Use case Preview:androidx.camera.core.Preview-7534171e-c1c5-4083-9fe2-7442c806478e ACTIVE D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and attached use case: [] for camera: 0 D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@dca1fc9[id=0]} Use case ImageCapture:androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-6ec784b0-678f-42ea-9e2c-bb74999cef0f ACTIVE D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and attached use case: [] for camera: 0 D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@dca1fc9[id=0]} Use case androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture@295f763 ACTIVE D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and attached use case: [] for camera: 0 D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and attached use case: [] for camera: 0 D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@dca1fc9[id=0]} Use cases [Preview:androidx.camera.core.Preview-7534171e-c1c5-4083-9fe2-7442c806478e, ImageCapture:androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-6ec784b0-678f-42ea-9e2c-bb74999cef0f, androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture@295f763] now ATTACHED D/UseCaseAttachState: All use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-7534171e-c1c5-4083-9fe2-7442c806478e135326493, androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-6ec784b0-678f-42ea-9e2c-bb74999cef0f205857170, androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture-9dc07c5c-a701-4cad-b1ec-7e1bad6d23cd43382627] for camera: 0 D/Camera2CameraImpl: mMeteringRepeating is ATTACHED, SessionConfig Surfaces: 3, CaptureConfig Surfaces: 1 D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and attached use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-7534171e-c1c5-4083-9fe2-7442c806478e135326493, androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-6ec784b0-678f-42ea-9e2c-bb74999cef0f205857170, androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture-9dc07c5c-a701-4cad-b1ec-7e1bad6d23cd43382627] for camera: 0 D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@dca1fc9[id=0]} Resetting Capture Session D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@dca1fc9[id=0]} Releasing session in state INITIALIZED D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@dca1fc9[id=0]} Attempting to force open the camera. D/CameraStateRegistry: tryOpenCamera(Camera@dca1fc9[id=0]) [Available Cameras: 1, Already Open: false (Previous state: null)] --> SUCCESS D/CameraStateRegistry: Recalculating open cameras:
    Camera                                       State                 
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Camera@dca1fc9[id=0]                         OPENING               
    Camera@2db1da[id=1]                          UNKNOWN               
    Camera@b5a2f94[id=2]                         UNKNOWN               
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Open count: 1 (Max allowed: 1) D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@dca1fc9[id=0]} Opening camera. D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@dca1fc9[id=0]} Transitioning camera internal state: INITIALIZED --> OPENING D/CameraStateMachine: New public camera state CameraState{type=OPENING, error=null} from OPENING and null D/CameraStateMachine: Publishing new public camera state CameraState{type=OPENING, error=null} D/UseCaseAttachState: All use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-7534171e-c1c5-4083-9fe2-7442c806478e135326493, androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-6ec784b0-678f-42ea-9e2c-bb74999cef0f205857170, androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture-9dc07c5c-a701-4cad-b1ec-7e1bad6d23cd43382627] for camera: 0 E/IMGSRV: :0: ObtainWindowParams: *piMaxBufCount is 64 E/IMGSRV: :0: ObtainWindowParams: *piMaxBufCount is 64 D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@dca1fc9[id=0]} Use case Preview:androidx.camera.core.Preview-7534171e-c1c5-4083-9fe2-7442c806478e ACTIVE D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and attached use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-7534171e-c1c5-4083-9fe2-7442c806478e135326493, androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-6ec784b0-678f-42ea-9e2c-bb74999cef0f205857170, androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture-9dc07c5c-a701-4cad-b1ec-7e1bad6d23cd43382627] for camera: 0 D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@dca1fc9[id=0]} Use case ImageCapture:androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-6ec784b0-678f-42ea-9e2c-bb74999cef0f ACTIVE D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and attached use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-7534171e-c1c5-4083-9fe2-7442c806478e135326493, androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-6ec784b0-678f-42ea-9e2c-bb74999cef0f205857170, androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture-9dc07c5c-a701-4cad-b1ec-7e1bad6d23cd43382627] for camera: 0 D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@dca1fc9[id=0]} Use case androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture@295f763 ACTIVE D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and attached use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-7534171e-c1c5-4083-9fe2-7442c806478e135326493, androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-6ec784b0-678f-42ea-9e2c-bb74999cef0f205857170, androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture-9dc07c5c-a701-4cad-b1ec-7e1bad6d23cd43382627] for camera: 0 D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@dca1fc9[id=0]} CameraDevice.onOpened() D/PreviewView: Surface requested by Preview. D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@dca1fc9[id=0]} Transitioning camera internal state: OPENING --> OPENED D/CameraStateRegistry: Recalculating open cameras:
    Camera                                       State                 
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Camera@dca1fc9[id=0]                         OPEN                  
    Camera@2db1da[id=1]                          UNKNOWN               
    Camera@b5a2f94[id=2]                         UNKNOWN               
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    Open count: 1 (Max allowed: 1) D/CameraStateMachine: New public camera state CameraState{type=OPEN, error=null} from OPEN and null D/CameraStateMachine: Publishing new public camera state CameraState{type=OPEN, error=null} D/UseCaseAttachState: All use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-7534171e-c1c5-4083-9fe2-7442c806478e135326493, androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-6ec784b0-678f-42ea-9e2c-bb74999cef0f205857170, androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture-9dc07c5c-a701-4cad-b1ec-7e1bad6d23cd43382627] for camera: 0 D/UseCaseAttachState: Active and attached use case: [androidx.camera.core.Preview-7534171e-c1c5-4083-9fe2-7442c806478e135326493, androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture-6ec784b0-678f-42ea-9e2c-bb74999cef0f205857170, androidx.camera.core.VideoCapture-9dc07c5c-a701-4cad-b1ec-7e1bad6d23cd43382627] for camera: 0 D/SurfaceViewImpl: Surface created. D/SurfaceViewImpl: Surface changed. Size: 1600x1200 D/PreviewView: Preview transformation info updated. TransformationInfo{cropRect=Rect(0, 0 - 1600, 1200), rotationDegrees=90, targetRotation=0} D/PreviewTransform: Transformation info set: TransformationInfo{cropRect=Rect(0, 0 - 1600, 1200), rotationDegrees=90, targetRotation=0} 1600x1200 false D/SurfaceViewImpl: Surface set on Preview. D/SyncCaptureSessionBase: [androidx.camera.camera2.internal.SynchronizedCaptureSessionBaseImpl@63e709f] getSurface...done D/CaptureSession: Opening capture session. D/DeferrableSurface: New surface in use[total_surfaces=3, used_surfaces=1](androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest$2@34f50ea} D/DeferrableSurface: use count+1, useCount=1 androidx.camera.core.SurfaceRequest$2@34f50ea D/DeferrableSurface: New surface in use[total_surfaces=3, used_surfaces=2](androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@fc63551} D/DeferrableSurface: use count+1, useCount=1 androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@fc63551 D/DeferrableSurface: New surface in use[total_surfaces=3, used_surfaces=3](androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@1d51342} D/DeferrableSurface: use count+1, useCount=1 androidx.camera.core.impl.ImmediateSurface@1d51342 I/BufferQueueProducer: [ImageReader-3264x2448f100m2-4436-0](this:0x771e0d3800,id:0,api:4,p:597,c:4436) connect(P): api=4 producer=(597:???) producerControlledByApp=false W/CameraX-core_ca: type=1400 audit(0.0:19912): avc: denied { search } for name="597" dev="proc" ino=17707 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c109,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:cameraserver:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 W/CameraX-core_ca: type=1400 audit(0.0:19913): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:graphics_debug_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=14043 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c109,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:graphics_debug_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.line" D/CaptureSession: Attempting to send capture request onConfigured D/CaptureSession: Issuing request for session. D/CaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession.onConfigured() mState=OPENED D/CaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession.onReady() OPENED D/StreamStateObserver: Update Preview stream state to STREAMING W/AMessage: failed to deliver message as target handler 1 is gone. W/AMessage: failed to deliver message as target handler 4 is gone. V/ViewRootImpl: debug enqueueInputEvent: event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=247.77058, y[0]=2056.1213, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x2, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=167186356, downTime=167186356, deviceId=1, source=0x1002 },processImmediately = true,mProcessInputEventsScheduled = false, this = android.view.ViewRootImpl@c2e0f91 : com.palfs.cameraxinjava/com.palfs.cameraxinjava.MainActivity V/ViewRootImpl: debug enqueueInputEvent: event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=242.7752, y[0]=2056.1213, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x2, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=167186489, downTime=167186356, deviceId=1, source=0x1002 },processImmediately = true,mProcessInputEventsScheduled = false, this
= android.view.ViewRootImpl@c2e0f91 : com.palfs.cameraxinjava/com.palfs.cameraxinjava.MainActivity D/CameraOrientationUtil: getRelativeImageRotation: destRotationDegrees=0, sourceRotationDegrees=90, isOppositeFacing=true, result=90 D/ImageCapture: Send image capture request [current, pending] = [0, 1] D/ImageCapture: issueTakePicture D/Camera2CameraImpl: {Camera@dca1fc9[id=0]} Issue capture request D/CaptureSession: Issuing capture request. E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument W/Binder:4436_3: type=1400 audit(0.0:19914): avc: denied { search } for name="597" dev="proc" ino=17707 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c109,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:cameraserver:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 544 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 545 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 546 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 547 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 548 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 549 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 2 W/ExifInterface: Stop reading file since a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop: 0 W/ExifInterface: Stop reading file since a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop: 0 W/ExifInterface: Stop reading file since a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop: 0 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 544 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 545 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 546 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 547 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 548 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 549 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 2 W/ExifInterface: Stop reading file since a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop: 0 W/ExifInterface: Stop reading file since a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop: 0 W/ExifInterface: Stop reading file since a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop: 0 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 544 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 545 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 546 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 547 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 548 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 549 W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 2 W/ExifInterface: Stop reading file since a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop: 0 I/chatty: uid=10109(com.palfs.cameraxinjava) CameraX-camerax identical 1 line W/ExifInterface: Stop reading file since a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop: 0 D/ViewRootImpl[Toast]: hardware acceleration = true , fakeHwAccelerated = false, sRendererDisabled = false, forceHwAccelerated = false, sSystemRendererDisabled = false D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x772f3f1000,api=1) D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x772f3f1000) **E/IMGSRV: :0: ObtainWindowParams: *piMaxBufCount is 0 I/libEGL: [MTK Game SDK] low_latency_mode(0) pid(-1) property(-1) E/IMGSRV: :0: ObtainWindowParams: *piMaxBufCount is 64 E/IMGSRV: :0: ObtainWindowParams: *piMaxBufCount is 64 D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x772f3f1000,api=1) E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid** argument D/View: [Warning] assignParent to null: this = android.widget.LinearLayout{2b4574d V.E...... ......ID 0,0-808,147}
```

What could I do to fix it?
Thank you very much in advance! ❤️

Comment: please add the error inside the ```

Comment: try to request permission in `recordVideo`

Comment: I have requested all permissions. The call back message is "Video has been saved successfully". but nothing has been saved.

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal not sure about what is the error! 
E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
E/IMGSRV: :0: ObtainWindowParams: *piMaxBufCount is 0
E/IMGSRV: :0: ObtainWindowParams: *piMaxBufCount is 64
I'm new in this mobile world.... I'm sorry.